# mssql xml without selfclosing nested nats

Tags: sql-server, xml

This might be a pretty stupid question, but I'm a complete noob regarding mssql language's native xml directives.

Scenario is as follows: there will be a parent table, and a children table. Father `1` shall have 0 children, whereas father `2` will have 2 children.

So, my generated xml (so far) is

```
<RootNode>
    <Father>
        <my_column_one>0</my_column_one>
        <Children />               <--- !!!!!! How can i get rid of this???
    </Father>
    <Father>
         <my_column_one>2</my_column_one>
         <Children>
             <Child>
                 <my_column_two>b</my_column_two>
             </Child>
             <Child>
                 <my_column_two>c</my_column_two>
             </Child>
         </Children>
    </Father>
</RootNode>
```

How can I get rid of the father `1` 's empty `<Children/>` tag?

I created a sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/99284/1

My query, so far, is

```
select
(
    SELECT FATHER.col_one AS my_column_one,
    (
        SELECT
        (
            SELECT CHILD.col_two AS my_column_two
            FROM   EIAC.EIAC.xml_debug_child CHILD
            WHERE  FATHER.col_one = CHILD.col_one
            FOR XML PATH('Child'),TYPE
        )
        FOR XML PATH('Children'),TYPE
    )
    FROM EIAC.EIAC.xml_debug_father FATHER
    for xml path('Father'), type
)
for xml path('RootNode')
```

Thank u so much!!!

Comment: Why is it a problem that it contains the `<Children />` element? That seems like a perfectly good way to represent a "collection" that in fact contains 0 items.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Obviously, it's perfectly correct xml syntax. Yet, it needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done quite easily:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE(id INT IDENTITY, col_one VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES('Father 1'),('Father 2');

DECLARE @t2 TABLE(id INT IDENTITY, father_id INT, col_two VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES(2,'Child 1'),(2,'Child 2');

select
(
    SELECT FATHER.col_one AS my_column_one,
        (
            SELECT CHILD.col_two AS my_column_two
            FROM   @t2 CHILD
            WHERE  FATHER.id = CHILD.father_id
            FOR XML PATH('Child'),TYPE
        ) AS [Children]
    FROM @t1 FATHER
    for xml path('Father'), type
)
for xml path('RootNode');
```

You wrapped the correlated sub-query within an additional sub-query `FOR XML PATH`, but you can add the nesting level `<children>` simply by naming the returned column. If there is nothing, you will not see the element.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank u SO much,  @Shnugo !!